# Taking a String and Capitalizing the first character - Why is this killing the browser

Tags: javascript, regex

given a string like bobby, I want to the function to return Bobby.

I have the following:

```
// Capitalizes the first letter.
function toTitleCase(str) {
    return str.replace(/(?:^|\s)\w/g, function(match) {
        return match.toUpperCase();
    });
}
```

For some reason this is killing the browser, any ideas why? Did I missing something with the REGEX that could be causing memory issues? thanks

Comment: Please define "killing the browser". Are you running this code in a loop of some kind?

Comment: It's not killing my browser ... by the way, "\b" does the same thing as your "^|\s" pattern - it's a zero-width matcher for a "word break". Your pattern could simply be `/\b\w/g`

Comment: works fine - http://jsfiddle.net/hwaY3/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why use regex for something like this?

```
var s = "my string";
s = s.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1);
console.log(s);
```

Regex is *quite* a bit more expensive to use than native string functions and as such should only be used when nothing else will solve your particular problem.

**Edit**

On another note, I'm not sure why it's causing your browser to bail, I have no issues running what you have in either FF or Chrome.

Comment: I believe he want to uppercase the first letter of each word in the string.

Comment: plus the string might be "       bobby".

Comment: @hogan: ah. guess it's arguable in that case which would be best to use :)

Comment: @pointy: nothing a `.trim()` can't solve (unless of course, you *want* to preserve the white space). Was just saying that regex should only be used when necessary - given the requirements he listed in his post, it's not :)